# Importar script js e arquivo de css dentro de um componente específico

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Bem, tenho um template que em determinadas páginas são necessários arquivos específicos para poder carregar. Então como eu faço uma importação de um arquivo css ou js na página que precisar?

Vamos dizer que a página **home** não precise, mas na página **user** sim.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o css pode ser importado desta forma

```
<style>
  @import './assets/styles/arquivo.css';
</style>
```

O script pode ser assim

```
<template>
  ... 
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    import * as mylib from '../assets/js/arquivo.js'
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ele até funciona, porém da erro, diz que o modulo não foi encontrado, mas o script faz o papel dele. Mas ai para de funcionar em segundos.

Comment: o css da erro de sintax